# Get a http request header value in Guice Module

Tags: playframework, guice

I need to get request header value and inject it into the constructor while a class is instantiated by Guice. It seems like Guice module does not have access to http.context! What is the right way to do this?

```
@Provides
protected class CustomerProvider @Inject()(dataClient: DataClient) extends Provider[CustomerRepository] {
  override def get(): CustomerRepository = {
    implicit val productType:String = Option(Context.Implicit.request.getHeader("abc")).getOrElse("xyz")
    val session = dataClient.session(productType)
    new CustomerRepository(session)
  }
```

I get the error message:  There is no HTTP Context available from here.
when I do the above!?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. There's a session context in Guice but in play there are no sessions. See [this][1. So when provides method run there's no specific context available.
What you can do is construct a stateless singleton and have the method accept the request context. something like :

```
@Provides
protected class CustomerProvider @Inject()(dataClient: DataClient) 
  extends Provider[CustomerRepository] {
   override def get(): CustomerRepository = {
       new CustomerRepository()
  }
}
class CustomerRepository @Inject()(collaborator: CCC) {
   def doSomething(param1, param2)(implicit request: RequestHeader)
}
```